# How to changed outgoing mail address from redhat based server

Tags: postfix, centos6

I would like change my out going email address username on postfix.
For example if i send mail from terminal like this

```
echo "testmail for serverfault"|mail -s "subject to test" serverfaultsfriends@example.net
```

But I received mail from the following  address root@example.com

I want to change this root@example.com into info@example.com. For your information there is no info user exist on myserver. I tried this [method](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-postfix-masquerade-change-email-mail-address.html) following but it not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does using `lmtp_generic_maps` instead of `smtp_generic_maps` help? Smtp is for connections over tcp port 25 and lmtp is for local mail (like using the mail tool). Posting the output of `postconf` makes is easier to help you, but make sure you remove any private/sensitive data.

Comment: I really dont know what is mean lmpt_generic_maps, I just solve my problems.This is production server it will lead to severe problem

Comment: The link you posted uses `smtp_generic_maps`, replace this with `lmtp_generic_maps`. You could also try to send mail using [telnet](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404584/sending-or-viewing-emails-using-telnet), this way you use smtp for sure.

Comment: `smtp_generic_maps` seems correct, looking at the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_generic_maps). It rewrites the address when it leaves the server. Maybe using just root instead root@domain.com will help in the rewrite file.

Comment: I cant able to access port 25 using telnet